# Curvature of the moment curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I would like to compute the curvature of the moment curve in $\mathbb R^n$:
$$
(s,s^2,s^3,\dots,s^n).
$$
I am especially interested in the curvature at $0$. But this is not parametrized by arc length. I also know a formula $$
  k(s)=\frac {|\gamma'(s)\times\gamma''(s)|}{|\gamma'(s)|^3}.
  $$
which works in the case $n=3$ only. I wonder if there is also a higher dimensional version of the above.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your curve is $\gamma(s): [a,b] \to \mathbb R^n$. Then we can find the the legnth of the curve on the interval $[a,t]$ using the formula

$$l(t) = \int_a^t \Vert \gamma'(s)\Vert ds$$

Note that if $\gamma$ is sufficiently well behaved then $l$ is strictly increasing and therefore has an inverse. Now define

$$\tilde \gamma (s) = \gamma(l^{-1}(s)).$$

It isn't difficult to see that the reparametrization $\tilde \gamma$ of $\gamma$ is now parametrized by arc length, so the standard formula for the curvature can be used.

Alternatively there is a more explicit formula

$$\kappa =  \frac{\sqrt{ \|\gamma'\|^2 \|\gamma''\|^2- \langle \gamma', \gamma''\rangle^2 } }{\|\gamma'\|^3}.$$

Comment: Thanks! I was just looking for the standard arbitrary dimension formula for the curvature. Do you know on which book I could find it? Thanks again!

Comment: And since $\bar \gamma$ is already parametrized by arc length, does that say $\left\|\bar\gamma'\right\|=1$, so that formula could be simplified? Or does that formula hold in the general setting where $\gamma$ is not necessarily parametrized by arc length?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give you a reference (I just retrieved it from my own notes), but I think you can derive it using Frenet frames. But you can find it on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Local_expressions_2).